# Configuring apache2 for mediawiki

Tags: apache2, mediawiki

For mediawiki to work on apache2 a file `/etc/apache2/conf/mediawiki` is required. Where can I find it?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Best is you [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/788658/edit) your question and add the link of which tutorial you're actually trying to follow and as well what steps you already did, so your question becomes more clear and easier to understand. Beside that there is no directory called `conf` in `/etc/apache2`.

Answer (score 1):

Good idea is to make a dedicated Virtual Host (who will run separate subdomain) for each MediaWiki on your server. Apache2 *virtualhost.conf* files are contained in the folder `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`.

For example, the VH configuration file could be named as follow (note its name must end with `.conf`): `/etc/apache2/sites-available/wiki.example.com.conf`. And its sample content should be something like:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName wiki.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@wiki.example.com

    # Redirect Requests to SSL
    Redirect permanent "/" "https://wiki.example.com/"

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wiki.example.com.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wiki.example.com.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

    <VirtualHost _default_:443>

            ServerName wiki.example.com
            ServerAdmin admin@wiki.example.com
            DocumentRoot /var/www/wiki.example.com

            # According MWiki Manual:Security
            php_flag register_globals off

            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wiki.example.com.error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wiki.example.com.access.log combined

            SSLEngine on
            SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/wiki.example.com.crt
            SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/wiki.example.com.key
            SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/wiki.example.com.root-bundle.crt

            <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </FilesMatch>

            <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                    SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
            </Directory>

            <Directory /var/www/wiki.example.com>
                    Options None FollowSymLinks
                    #Allow .htaccess
                    AllowOverride All
                    Require all granted
                    <IfModule security2_module>
                            SecRuleEngine Off
                            # or disable only problematic rules
                    </IfModule>
            </Directory>

            # According to MWiki Manual:Security
            <Directory /var/www/wiki.example.com/images>
                    # Ignore .htaccess files
                    AllowOverride None
                    # Serve HTML as plaintext, don't execute SHTML
                    AddType text/plain .html .htm .shtml .php .phtml .php5
                    # Don't run arbitrary PHP code.
                    php_admin_flag engine off
                    # If you've other scripting languages, disable them too.
            </Directory>

            #According to MWiki Manual:Security
            <Directory /var/www/wiki.example.com/images/deleted>
                    Deny from all
                    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
                    Require local
            </Directory>

    </VirtualHost>

</IfModule>
```

Note that, this example is for configuration with enabled HTTPS/SSL. For pure HTTP it must look like:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName wiki.example.com
    ServerAdmin admin@wiki.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wiki.example.com

    # According MWiki Manual:Security
    php_flag register_globals off

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wiki.example.com.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wiki.example.com.access.log combined

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
            SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/wiki.example.com>
            Options None FollowSymLinks
            #Allow .htaccess
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
            <IfModule security2_module>
                    SecRuleEngine Off
                    # or disable only problematic rules
            </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    # According to MWiki Manual:Security
    <Directory /var/www/wiki.example.com/images>
            # Ignore .htaccess files
            AllowOverride None
            # Serve HTML as plaintext, don't execute SHTML
            AddType text/plain .html .htm .shtml .php .phtml .php5
            # Don't run arbitrary PHP code.
            php_admin_flag engine off
            # If you've other scripting languages, disable them too.
    </Directory>

    #According to MWiki Manual:Security
    <Directory /var/www/wiki.example.com/images/deleted>
            Deny from all
            AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
            Require local
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

To activate the VirtyalHost you need to run:

```xml
sudo a2ensite wiki.example.com.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

Read also:

- [How to redirect in local domain web site www.mydomain.com/website to www.mydomain.com](https://askubuntu.com/q/1111896/566421)
- [When does Ubuntu 16.04 use /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt?](https://askubuntu.com/q/900400/566421)
- [Let's Encrypt, Apache2 - Editing vhosts properly](https://askubuntu.com/q/893359/566421)