# Let's Encrypt, Apache2 - Editing vhosts properly

Tags: apache2, ssl, letsencrypt

What is the proper way to edit `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled` when there is `example.com.conf` and `example.com-le-ssl.conf`?

Should I edit both the files when changing something? Or only one and then somehow force `certbot-auto` to fix it?

Comment: Not familiar with `Encrypt`, but first off you edit `site-available` not `sites-enabled` and reload apache. And if `example.com-le-ssl.conf` is linked to `example.com.conf` I would think reloading apache would also update and changes made.

Comment: @George, I meant sites-available :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what is the right answer of your question, but I would suggest you the following simplification:

**1.** Force all users to use HTTPS. The definition of the HTTP VirtualHost should look like this:

```bsh
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName example.com

        # Redirect Requests to HTTPS
        Redirect permanent "/" "https://example.com/"

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

In this way you will need maintain only the configuration of the HTTPS VirtualHost.

**2.** As soon as you [generate](https://askubuntu.com/a/900433/566421) "Let's Encrypt" ssl certificate files, describe them manually into the definition of the HTTP**S** VirtualHost:

```bsh
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>

        ServerName example.com
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com            

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chain.pem

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com.access.log combined

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html    
        <Directory /var/www/html>
              # etc...
        </Directory>

        # etc...

    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

**3.** Insert the definitions of both VirtualHosts into a single configuration file:

```bsh
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # etc...
</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>
        # etc...
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

This file could be `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf`.

**4.** Don't forget to `a2dissite` unnecessary VirtualHosts (respectively `a2ensite` the necessary ones) and restart Apache.

**5.** Edit root's crontab and add a job which will try to renew the certificates, every week, for example. Type `sudo crontab -e` and add this line at the bottom:

```bsh
0 3 * * 0 /usr/bin/letsencrypt renew  >> /var/log/letsencrypt-renew.week-$(date +%W).log 2>&1
```

That's it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. One note though: some say to keep the `VirtualHost` definitions in two separate files as a general rule. It allows enabling and disabling each protocol independently.

Comment: @MiroJ., I"m agree with this but in case the HTTP VH is permanently redirected to the HTTPS VS the clients will end up with 404 Page not found, if the second is disabled, but the first is not.