# Can I host two sites, one domain based and on ip based, on the same apache server?

Tags: server, apache2, virtualhost

Am trying to host website example.com on my current Ubuntu server.

I have created the directories for it: /var/www/html/example.com/public_html

and within sites-enabled I created example.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

    <Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/example.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Just changed the DNS so it will take a while to make sure that part works.

However, I'm currently using the same server with just the IP address to do some Perl scripts they're called by x.x.x.x/cgi-bin/perlscript.pl

And that part has stopped working.

The error log contains

> AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/: No matching
>   DirectoryIndex
>   (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found,
>   and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive

So since I just set up just the conf file for the domain name based server, did I somehow mess up everything?

Can Ubuntu host two virtual servers where one is domain name based and the other just IP based?

**---UPDATE---**

The DNS update was quick enough that new domain website, example.com, works.  Now I just need to be able to get back to working off my other website based purely on IP address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating additional virtual host Ubuntu Server 16.04.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031543/creating-additional-virtual-host-ubuntu-server-16-04-3)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry my mistake, turns out I missed the part of disabling the 000-default.conf

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
```

And when I made the conf files I had to make two.  One for example.com and the other for the IP address website (a different website).  I simply replaced all instances of

> example.com

with the actual IP address for the website

For anyone coming across this same problem I found this link: [How To Configure Apache Virtual Hosts In Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://www.ostechnix.com/configure-apache-virtual-hosts-ubuntu-part-1/)