# WordPress website on separate port on my nextcloud server?

Tags: server, apache2, snap, wordpress, nextcloud

I am running a very small home server using an old machine, nothing special.

It is running Ubuntu 18.04 with live patch and the latest SNAP install of Nextcloud. It is live on the internet via my personal URL and I have my dynamic DNS through my Netgear router to keep my IP up to date in case my ISP changes it.

Here's what I'm hoping to be able to do...

I would like to backtrack and preface this with the fact that I'm pretty much a noob to all of this and it is kind of a hobby for me to try to learn some basic coding, networking, server management, etc.

Ok, back to the point. I'd like to use this same server to host a WordPress website not sure what it's purpose will be yet. I really just want to toy with building a website. I would like to, again, use this same machine and the same URL and just place the website at a different port or address.

Example of what I mean: My nextcloud server is accessed at "mypersonalurl.cloud" I'd like to keep that the way it is and access my web page via "mypersonalurl.cloud:(insert different port here)" or "mypersonalurl.cloud/extensionwebpage"

Thanks in advance for any help that can be offered to me. I've seen several things out there on running two sites at the same IP, but it seems it would be a little different with Nextcloud, especially the SNAP install.

Comment: Hello, WeeseNXT. Using a web server on a custom port will cause some inconvenience. For example you (or your visitors) will need to enter the port each time wen you access the WordPress site's URL. So I would advice you yo setup an additional virtual host. Here are two topics that could be interesting for you: [Creating additional Virtual Host](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031607/566421) and [How to install WordPress](https://askubuntu.com/a/941947/566421).

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't setup NextCloud via Snap, my instance is installed by a native installation. Probably you will need to setup Apache as reverse proxy for you NextClud installed via Snap.

Comment: I can't get any of this to work with the SNAP installation as it doesn't have apache2 or anything like that as a prerequisite. I'm starting to find this will be more complicated with the SNAP install. I can't get apache and nextcloud to listen on the same ports. Not sure what the resolve for this will be. May not be possible when installed this way.

Answer (score 0):

Port or subdomain should be easy in either circumstance this is what I would do:

If you can do a subdomain, so say blog.mypersonalurl.cloud you can just do a standard EE install: https://easyengine.io/docs/install/

If you prefer a different port you would just edit that port in both phphmyadmin and Apache or NGINX. Here is a guide for that: https://helpdeskgeek.com/networking/change-apache-listening-port/ for Apache, and here for NGINX https://websiteforstudents.com/change-nginx-http-server-port-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04/

Either way it should only take you a few seconds to edit and should work well!

Comment: I'm a little confused on setting up a subdomain. Also EE states only good for 16.04. Is this still the case?

Comment: I think honestly I'd like to use a different domain entirely. Is this possible?

Comment: You can use higher versions for EE. I think I used it for 20. You also don't have to use EE. I just find it really easy to get up and running.

Comment: Yes, you can use any domain you want really. Just be aware that you are publicly making that domain available to anyone.

Comment: it is saying "please make sure ports 80 and 443 are free" when trying to set up via EE.

Comment: the problem I'm running into is getting nextcloud and this to run on the same server