# I want to access two websites from same IP but diff ports

Tags: server, apache2

I have deployed my apps on  apache and can access them from  `sites-available` . but at a time I can enable 1 I think. how to enable both at a time in on diff port?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating additional Virtual Host Ubuntu Server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031543/creating-additional-virtual-host-ubuntu-server)

Comment: @pa4080 No its diff problem .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the 2nd port to listen to at `/etc/apache2/ports.conf`. It will have a line looking like

```
Listen 80
```

add a 2nd line to it with another portnumber (`Listen 81` as an example).

Your config in `sites-available` has a `<VirtualHost *:80` for port 80. Change that for the 2nd site to `<VirtualHost *:81>`. Change ServerName and DocumentRoot to the 2nd site. Also change the name of the error log so you have logs for both sites and not one combining them.

If you also need ssl: `ports.conf` will also have a section for that and you can duplicate that too: add a port inside the IfModule sections.

Restart apache for it to take effect.

Comment: thanks for reply sir are you saying that I can create 2 diff files like  siteone.conf and sitetwo.conf  and it should work ?

Comment: yes! put them in sites-AVAILABLE and symlink them  to sites-ENABLED. Removing the symlink disables that site and you only need to edit the one in availble