# Setting up multiple virtual hosts for one domain name

Tags: apache2

I have a web server that has a domain name sub.mydomain.com, and I have installed multiple WordPress sites in /www/html/, hence, I have a few sites with the same domain name. For e.g. sub.mydomain.com/site1, sub.mydomain.com/site2 and sub.mydomain.com/site3.

The sites all run on the apache default virtual host conf file.

Now that I plan to enable SSL for few of the sites and I encountered an issue because there is only one conf for all sites. I am not sure how separate each site and create a conf for each of the sites so that I can control which sites will be SSL enabled and which sites will not.

Would this be possible? Any advices would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The SSL/TLS certificate is issued per [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name), for example: `sub.mydomain.com` or `mydomain.com`, etc. The certificate file could contains certificates for couple FQDNs. For example if you are using "Let's Encrypt" (CertBot) the following command will generate two certificates placed in the same file:

```
sudo letsencrypt --apache certonly --rsa-key-size 4096 --email admin@email.com -d mydomain.com -d sub.mydomain.com
```

If I understand correctly you are having only one Virtual Host and several different sites that are accessible via different URIs. So in this case you will need a certificate for `sub.mydomain.com`, the URIs `/site1`, `/site2`, etc. do not matter.

More information about the Apache's configuration and how to generate certificates by using of Let's Encrypt you can find within the answers of the questions:

- [When does Ubuntu 16.04 use /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/900400/when-does-ubuntu-16-04-use-etc-apache2-ssl-apache-crt)
- [Let's Encrypt, Apache2 - Editing vhosts properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/893359/lets-encrypt-apache2-editing-vhosts-properly)

Comment: The CA that I am using is DigiCert, I was told to purchase a multi-domain SSL based on my situation. But I am not sure how to configure my conf file since all of my websites are using the default one.