# How to redirect in local domain web site www.mydomain.com/website to www.mydomain.com

Tags: apache2, webserver, redirect, mediawiki

I have install simple web service (MediaWiki) in my local server. 
In my DSN server I have set IP address to this webserver, so now when I call in browser (this works only in my domain IP range) `www.mydomain.com` I get website of Apache, when I call `www.mydomain.com/mediawiki` then my site of mediawiki is open.

Can I make that in browser (still I whant this to work only in domain range) I call `www.mydomain.com` that opens - redirects to `www.mydomain.com/mediawiki`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this purposes you need to change the content of default Virtual Host configuration file `000-default.conf` that is located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/`. Or you can create a new Virtual Host configuration file, then you must disable `000-default.conf` and enable the new one.

Let's assume you decide to create a new VH configuration file, lets call it `my.wiki.org.conf`, it should be located in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and its content should be something as:

```xml
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName my.wiki.org
    ServerAdmin your-admin@email.com

    # According MWiki Manual:Security
    php_flag register_globals off

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my.wiki.org.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/my.wiki.org.access.log combined

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/my.wiki.org"

    <Directory "/var/www/my.wiki.org">  
        Options None FollowSymLinks
        #Allow .htaccess:
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # According to MWiki Manual:Security
    <Directory "/var/www/my.wiki.org/images">
        Options -Indexes
        # Allow .htaccess files
        AllowOverride All
        # Serve HTML as plaintext, don't execute SHTML
        AddType text/plain .html .htm .shtml .php .phtml .php5
        # Don't run arbitrary PHP code.
        php_admin_flag engine off
        # If you've other scripting languages, disable them too.
    </Directory>

    # According to MWiki Manual:Security
    <Directory "/var/www/my.wiki.org/images/deleted">
        Deny from all           
        AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
        Require local
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Then disable `000-default.conf`, enable `my.wiki.org.conf` and restart (or reload) Apache's configuration:

```xml
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
sudo a2ensite my.wiki.org.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2.service
```

**The key point here is that you changed [`DocumentRoot`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#documentroot) of the Virtual Host to the installation directory of MediaWiki. I assuming here this directory is `/var/www/my.wiki.org`.**

---

In addition if you want to serve your wiki articles by `my.wiki.org/wiki/Article_name`, instead of `my.wiki.org/index.php/Article_name`, you can add the following lines in the `.htaccess` file, located in the `DocumentRoot` directory:

```xml
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^/?wiki(/.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/?images/thumb/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2 [L,QSA,B]

    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
    RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
    RewriteRule ^/?images/thumb/archive/[0-9a-f]/[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)px-.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/thumb.php?f=$1&width=$2&archived=1 [L,QSA,B]
</ifModule>
```

And modify your `LocalSettings.php` as follow:

```php
$wgScriptPath = "";
$wgScriptExtension = ".php";
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";
```

References about this additional part:

- https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL
- https://shorturls.redwerks.org/

---

For test purposes you could add some lines, as the shown below, in your `/etc/hosts` file to access your wiki via FDQN instead of *localhost* or IP address in your LAN ([more details](https://askubuntu.com/a/900594/566421)):

```bsh
127.0.0.1 localhost my.wiki.org  # access my.wiki.org from the same machine
192.168.0.150 my.wiki.org        # access my.wiki.org that is hosted on another LAN machine with IP 192.168.0.150
```

One more security note for public servers:

- I would enable [HTTPS](https://askubuntu.com/a/900433/566421) and would [redirect all users](https://askubuntu.com/a/873876/566421) to it.

Read also:

- [Configuring apache2 for mediawiki](https://askubuntu.com/q/788658/566421)
- [Let's Encrypt, Apache2 - Editing vhosts properly](https://askubuntu.com/q/893359/566421)